# "Chrome.tabs is not supported..."

Tags: google-chrome

I always get this error in Chrome's console.

```
Uncaught Error: chrome.tabs is not supported in content scripts. See the content scripts documentation for more details.
```

But everything works fine.

Anyone knows what is causing this and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Typically, the cause is a misbehaving extension. In my case it was "MeasureIt!".
To identify, which extension is making troubles, you can either

### deactivate them one by one and test

1. deactivate all the extensions
2. ensure the error is gone
3. activate extensions one by one
4. test if the error reappears, repeat from step 3

or

### search their source code

1. open `chrome://extensions`
2. activate "Developer mode" in the top right corner
3. now you can open `background.html` for every extension
4. Ctrl+F, type in "chrome.tabs" to search for suspicious code spots
5. give feedback to the extension creator

Comment: Nice one :) Was 'Measureit!' for me also..

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use `chrome.tabs` in content scripts. According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts),

> ...content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

So, you can only use the `chrome.tabs` API in background pages or other extension pages.
You can use [extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging) to request that a background page use `chrome.tabs`.

Comment: I don't get what is using chrome.tabs. Could it be one of my Chrome extensions?

Comment: Yes, this error can only be thrown by a Chrome extension (as of now).

Comment: For me, it was MeasureIt! causing the error.

Comment: @weng If you still get the error, try disabling some extensions in groups and see if the error is removed.

Comment: MeasureIt! Also causing this error for. Can't be bothered to debug someone else's code so I'm just bearing with it for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an extension using the `chrome.tabs` permission, but without specifying that it does so in the `manifest.json` packaged with the extension.  The trick is not just to find the extension that uses `chrome.tabs`, but to find the one that does so without announcing it.

Start with a more automated approach (multi-line commands for readability):
On *nix:

```
$ find . -type f \
> | xargs grep -l chrome.tabs \
> | cut -d '/' -f 2 \
> | uniq
```

On Windows, using PowerShell:

```
> gci -rec |? {-not $_.PSIsContainer} `
>> | sls 'chrome.tabs' `
>> | select -Unique Path `
>> |% {$_.Path.Split('\')[10] } `
>> | select -Unique
>>
```

**Then** go to the `chrome://extensions` tab to match directories in the results to extension names, and click the permissions of each one to see who isn't copping to their usage of `chrome.tabs`.  Note that on the 4th line of the PowerShell snippet, I index '10' because that's how many path components there are from `C:\` to the `Extensions` directory; it could be different on your system.

In my case, I fully automated the search by tacking on a couple more segments to the pipeline:

```
$ find . type f \
> | xargs grep -l chrome.tabs \
> | cut -d '/' -f 2 \
> | uniq \
> | xargs -I % find % -name 'manifest.json' \
> | xargs grep -L tabs
hipbfijinpcgfogaopmgehiegacbhmob/16.0.544_0/manifest.json
hipbfijinpcgfogaopmgehiegacbhmob/17.1_0/manifest.json
hipbfijinpcgfogaopmgehiegacbhmob/18.1_0/manifest.json
```

Now, looking in `chrome://extensions`:

[image]

Busted.

[image]